# How to replace a string with char from a hashmap?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a morse code program that can encode. Now I want it to decode but I do not know how to replace a string of encrypted characters with the letter from my hash map.

Here is the method for decoding:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++){
        if(i != 0){
            morse.append(' ');
        }
        morse.append(codeLibrary.get(userInput.charAt(i))); //Currentely the same as encoding, this line needs to change
    }
    return morse.toString();
```

And here is my hashmap:

```
public static final java.util.Map<Character, String> codeLibrary;
 static{
    codeLibrary = new HashMap<>();
    codeLibrary.put('a',".-");      codeLibrary.put('b',"-...");
    codeLibrary.put('c',"-.-.");    codeLibrary.put('d',"-..");
    codeLibrary.put('e',".");       codeLibrary.put('f',"..-.");
    codeLibrary.put('g',"--.");     codeLibrary.put('h',"....");
    codeLibrary.put('i',"..");      codeLibrary.put('j',".---");
    codeLibrary.put('k',"-.-");     codeLibrary.put('l',".-..");
    codeLibrary.put('m',"--");      codeLibrary.put('n',"-.");  
    codeLibrary.put('o',"---");     codeLibrary.put('p',".--.");
    codeLibrary.put('q',"--.-");    codeLibrary.put('r',".-.");
    codeLibrary.put('s',"...");     codeLibrary.put('t',"-");
    codeLibrary.put('u',"..-");     codeLibrary.put('v',"...-");
    codeLibrary.put('w',".--");     codeLibrary.put('x',"-..-");
    codeLibrary.put('y',"-.--");    codeLibrary.put('z',"--..");
    codeLibrary.put('1',".----");   codeLibrary.put('2',"..---");
    codeLibrary.put('3',"...--");   codeLibrary.put('4',".----");
    codeLibrary.put('5',".....");   codeLibrary.put('6',"-....");
    codeLibrary.put('7',"--...");   codeLibrary.put('8',"---..");
    codeLibrary.put('9',"----.");   codeLibrary.put('0',"-----");
    codeLibrary.put(' ',"/");
```

Comment: If you're open to using Guava, you could use a [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html).

Comment: This seems like it would have been the right thing to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a separate Map, one that is a `Map<String, Character>`, and again a `HashMap<String, Character>` would work well, fill it with el

---

If this is a school assignment, then I believe that this is the solution. If this is for real applications, then yeah, go ahead and use the Guava BiMap library as suggested by [Jake King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465378/jake-king).

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> This seems like a very long way of doing this. Is it not possible to insert the value to retrieve the key?

That's not how ordinary Maps work. You use the Key to get the Value, not the other way around. But this is not hard to do nor very "long". You could fill both Maps in the same loop even.

---

For example,...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MorseFun {
   public static final String[] LETTER_CODES = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..",
         ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.",
         "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--",
         "-..-", "-.--", "--.." };
   public static final String[] NUMBER_CODES = { "-----", ".----", "..---",
         "...--", ".----", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----." };

   private static Map<Character, String> charToCodeMap = new HashMap<>();
   private static Map<String, Character> codeToCharMap = new HashMap<>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 0; i < LETTER_CODES.length; i++) {
         char c = (char) ('a' + i);
         String s = LETTER_CODES[i];
         charToCodeMap.put(c, s);
         codeToCharMap.put(s, c);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_CODES.length; i++) {
         char c = (char) ('0' + i);
         String s = LETTER_CODES[i];
         charToCodeMap.put(c, s);
         codeToCharMap.put(s, c);
      }



   }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very long way of doing this. Is it not possible to insert the value to retrieve the key?

Comment: @mungostrap: that's not how ordinary Maps work. You use the Key to get the Value, not the other way around. But this is not hard to do. You could fill both Maps in the same loop even.

Comment: @mungostrap A really inefficient and ugly way to do it without an external library would be to [iterate through the Map.Entry set](http://stackoverflow.com/q/46898/3735079) and equal the `Entry#getValue()` to retrieve the `Entry#getKey()`. But again, this is very bad, you should go for this answer solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to play the devil's advocate you could just create a simple utility method that searches through a `Map`'s `Set<Entry>` until it finds the value you need;

```
public static Character convertMorseToChar(String yourMorse){
    for(Map.Entry<Character,String> e : codeLibrary.entrySet()){
        if(e.getValue().equals(yourMorse)) return e.getKey();
    }
    return null;
}
```

All the above method does is runs an [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with), and loops over a `Set` collection of [`Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects gained from the `Map` using the `.entrySet()` method. Each `Entry` represents a Key/Value pair in the map. When it finds the `Entry` with the value you parsed into the method (your morse code), it returns that `Entry`'s key (the character you are looking for).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to Java and maps. Could you please explain what this is doing?

Comment: @mungostrap - Sure, no problem. I added in a brief description of the code and some links that should help you with any further reading you might need.

Comment: Thanks dude, i have opted to try Hovercrafts way